How to nicely set up a library that contains Spring Components
We uses Spring Boot backend on all our projects so we grouped the most commonly used components in a team's library. To make the components available to the calling app, we have to add the library path to the component scan which is quite ugly and sometimes problematic imho:
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.mycomp.myappApplication , com.mycomp.mylib.repository.azure, com.mycomp.mylib.jackson")
public class MyappApplication {
..}

There used to be a hack in Spring context 3 to dynamically add component using SingletonBeanFactoryLocator, eg bellow in Scriptella lib, but this has been depreciated :
 private static ThreadLocal<BeanFactory> getGlobalThreadLocal() {
        BeanFactoryLocator locator = SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance(BEAN_FACTORY_XML_PATH);
        BeanFactoryReference ref = locator.useBeanFactory(FACTORY_BEAN_NAME);
        StaticApplicationContext ctx = (StaticApplicationContext) ref.getFactory();
        if (!ctx.containsBean(THREAD_LOCAL_BEAN_NAME)) {
            ctx.registerSingleton(THREAD_LOCAL_BEAN_NAME, ThreadLocal.class);
        }
        return (ThreadLocal) ctx.getBean(THREAD_LOCAL_BEAN_NAME);
    }

Is there a way to dynamically register a spring bean in a Spring Boot application from a libray that is not in the default application component scan?
Thanks


@Bean method 2) create Autoconfiguration so it will be picked up just by library beeing in the classpath


Spring Boot can leverage auto configuration which will automatically pick up everything you need. It is just a matter of adding some meta-data to your jar and that will make it automatically work.
